# How I can see Auto Attribute suggestion for Android Studio in Java

Tags: java, android

The XML file does not show auto suggestion in attribute. I have already done Invalidated catches/restart,deleted.iml and.idea file. I have also installed auto suggestion plugin codota.

Here orientation is empty, doesn't show vertical or horizontal, also same in TextView

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

To use auto attributes, add the tools namespace to the root element of each XML file where you'd like to use them, as shown here:

`<app xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">`